# How to pass String(phone number) for Quickreply? :D

Tags: android, string, sms

I have a problem(again)...now i want to pass a String from one Activity to another.

The first Activity is SMSReceiver, i make a ListView for contact's number and message's here.

This is the complete code :

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int NOTIF_ID = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            str += "You Get New SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";

        Toast.makeText(arg0, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String tickerText = str;

        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        String contentTitle = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        String contentText = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, SMSReply.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, intent, 0);

        notif.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, contentTitle, contentText, pi);
        notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notif);

        String tempSMS = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        Intent pass = new Intent();
        Bundle bundlePass = new Bundle();

        bundlePass.putString("key", tempSMS);
        pass.putExtras(bundlePass);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the PART OF SMSReceiver that i used for passing a String via Bundle and Intent

```
String tempSMS = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        Intent pass = new Intent();
        Bundle bundlePass = new Bundle();

        bundlePass.putString("key", tempSMS);
        pass.putExtras(bundlePass);
```

Now, this is the complete SMSReply Class, the class that i want to get a phone number(String) from SMSReceiver Class(so user don't have to type it again)

```
public class SMSReply extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText etPhone, etMessage;
Button bSend;
String phone, message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reply);

    etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
    etMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
    bSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
    bSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent get = new Intent();

    Bundle bundleGet = get.getExtras();
    phone = bundleGet.getString("answer");
    etPhone.setText(phone);

    phone = etPhone.getText().toString();
    message = etMessage.getText().toString();

    if (phone.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0) {
        sendSms(phone, message);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Please enter both phone number and message",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void sendSms(String phone2, String message2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not Delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

And this is the PART OF SMSReply class, where i put some code's for taking a String from SMSReceiver and set that String in my EditText :D

```
Intent get = new Intent();

    Bundle bundleGet = get.getExtras();
    phone = bundleGet.getString("answer");
    etPhone.setText(phone);

    phone = etPhone.getText().toString();
    message = etMessage.getText().toString();
```

Thats All!
Please help me, and thank you very much! :D

PS : Sory for the long post, and sory if my English is not good, English is not my native languange :D

Comment: Please help me if you have some free time..this question is still unanswered..you can comment if you don't understand what i mean in this question. I check this everyday. Thanks all :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting the extra arguments in bundle, you put that bundle in **pass** Intent and you are doing nothing of that **pass** Intent. Actually, you should pass these bundle into the intent which you are passing for Notification, i.e. in **intent** Intent.
`intent.putExtras(bundlePass);`.

Similarly, while reading the argument from bundle, you are accessing it from a new intent which is not the actual one which comes, So use `Bundle bundleGet = getIntent().getExtras();`

Comment: Thank you Sir :D
I think i already use my pass Intent to pass my Bundle in this line of code (the last line):
<pre>pass.putExtras(bundlePass);<code>

And i don't know why, <pre>Bundle bundleGet = getIntent().getExtras();<code> is still not working :D

Thanks Sir :D

Comment: Sorry Sir, how to create a code line, i mean like what you did in your answer..i read the help article and i just found <pre><code> but it's not working :(
Thanks :D

Comment: 'pass' is not the one intent which is used for notification, it is 'intent' so when this notification is clicked, the 'intent' will run as you send in lines Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, SMSReply.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, intent, 0);

Comment: Sorry but it's still not working..can you give me the code?but i think i have followed your instruction's Thanks :D

Comment: Replace
pass.putExtras(bundlePass); with intent.putExtras(bundlePass);
and replace
Bundle bundleGet = get.getExtras(); with Bundle bundleGet = getIntent().getExtras();

Answer (score 1):

In SMSReceiver

```
Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, SMSReply.class);
intent.putExtras("key", tempSMS);
startActivity(intent);
```

In SmsReply

```
Bundle bund=getIntent().getExtras();
String number=bund.getString("key");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sir :D
Well, i have some problem's :
1. Do you mean Intent.putExtra instead of Intent.putExtras?coz there's an error :D
2. I can't use startActivity() method in SMSReceiver coz i extends BroadcastReceiver :D

Thanks Sir :D